Loading progress going from 0 to 100 automatically without full load of scene
I'm making a progress bar in unity for loading scenes but the bar goes from 0 to 100 without stopping in the middle
public void Loading(string sceneID)
{
    screen.SetActive(true);
    StartCoroutine(LoadingAsync(sceneID));
}

public IEnumerator LoadingAsync(string sceneID)
{
    yield return null;

    AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneID);
    operation.allowSceneActivation = false;
    
    while (!operation.isDone)
    {
        float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress / .9f);
        Debug.Log(progress * 100 + "%");
        loadingBar.value = progress * 100f;
        loadingPer.text = progress * 100f + "%";
        


        if (operation.progress >= .9f) { operation.allowSceneActivation = true; }

        yield return null;
    }

}

Here is the debug:

Expected the loading bar progress to be smooth but it just goes from 0 to 100

local scene loads are usually insanely faster.. so it can be basically instant

IIRC some load operations don't update their progress correctly in the Editor but do update their progress correctly in builds. I can't remember offhand if this is one of those, but it's worth checking how it looks in a build.

With Mathf.clamp01 you only have 0 or 1 where 1 is your 100%.
Change this code to get the real progress
while (!operation.isDone)
    {
        float progress = operation.progress * 100);
        Debug.Log(progress + "%");
        loadingBar.value = progress;
        loadingPer.text = progress + "%";
        


        if (operation.progress >= .9f) { operation.allowSceneActivation = true; }

        yield return null;
    }

